# Why Gradle 5 (5.6.3) made an unexpected decision during component resolution?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-multi-project-build

I have a very large multi-project java build. After the update to the Gradle 5(4.10.3->5.6.3), one of the most terrifying things is unexpected failures during dependency resolution:

```
...
dependencies {
// I know about the deprecation of 'compile', with 'implementation' I have the same problems
    compile project(":Monitor")
    compile project(":WFPlugins-Server")
    compile project(":web-spring")
    compile project(":Security")
    compile project(":Client")
}
...
```

For me it's clear as the day, it's should be a project dependency. But I receive:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.



* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':SpringWFS:compileJava'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':SpringWFS:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.company:WFPlugins-Server:1.12.

     Required by:
         project :SpringWFS
```

So the gradle is trying to resolve this as an **ExternalModuleDependency** [in terms of the gradle] instead of **DefaultProjectDependency** and build is failing as expected

Is someone solves this problem?

remarks:

1. Please don't propose composite builds (it isn't possible at this moment of time but I'm working on it)
2. Change the build system (We have a really large project) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reasons Gradle would replace a project dependency with a module dependency are:

- if there is a substitution rule defined. Check if you have any defined.
- if you reference `WFPlugins-Server` elsewhere in your build as a binary dependency, and it appears as part of the `SpringWFS` dependency graph, *and* it has a higher version than the project.

In the last case, you can tweak the resolution strategy [to prefer project over modules](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy:preferProjectModules()).

Comment: 1. there're no substitution rules yet.
2. I have no exact this situation.
 I'll try tweak anyway, but I'm in the middle of debugging of the dependency resolution :)